# Django, detect if object.filter returns 0 objects

Tags: django, orm

I got such table structure

```
class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Car(models.Model):
    vin_number = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    item = models.OneToOneField(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(null=True)

class Yacht(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='')
    boat_type = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='', null=True)
    item = models.OneToOneField(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(default='')
    year = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=0)
```

So, both Car and Yacht has relation with Item table

If I have only item id in request, what is the right way to write such query

```
    data = request.POST
    item = Car.objects.filter(item_id=data['item_id']).first()
    if not item:
        item = Yacht.objects.filter(item_id=data['item_id']).first()
```

Is there any way not to use if/else statement?

Comment: Can you give more details? and isn't `if not item:` working?

Comment: @Hisham___Pak - why `if not item` will not work?

Comment: I am asking what is your problem.

Comment: @Hisham___Pak - problem is that I need to make 2 queries, both for Car and Yacht. And if I have more tables which have `OneToOne` relation with `Item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to look into the Car and Yacht model. Directly use the Item model's OneToOne relationship

```
item = Item.objects.filter(id = data['id']).first
```

This item has a specific id that relates to one of the other model. You can access them using

```
if item.car:
   car = item.car
else:
   yacht = item.yacht
```

But I guess you also need to add {{ related_name='tags', related_query_name='tag' }} to your OneToOne field for both car and yacht.
I would recommend that you check this out https://kite.com/python/docs/django.db.models.ForeignKey.

For more detail go to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `exists()`.

```
Car.objects.filter(item_id=data['item_id']).exists()
Yacht.objects.filter(item_id=data['item_id']).exists()
```

It returns you `True` or `False`.
Links to official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists).

Comment: But I still need to use `if/else` to check the result for the first query

Comment: I think you use not a good database structure. I would separate items by types as you did in models and add id field in every model as I don't see any pros for a separate `Item` model.